# Django: Either provide a url or define a get_absolute_url method on the Model

Tags: django

Whenever I submit my form, the data is added to the database but I am getting an error

```
ImproperlyConfigured at /issue/new/
No URL to redirect to.  Either provide a url or define a get_absolute_url method on the Model.
```

Even though I already have a `get_absolute_url` in my model

EDIT: The above is when the form is valid, when the form is invalid, I get

```
TemplateResponseMixin requires either a definition of 'template_name' or an implementation of 'get_template_names()'
```

model:

```
class Issue(models.Model):
    CATEGORIES = (
        ('A', 'Asd'),
        ('B', 'Bd'),
        ('C', 'Cu'),
        ('D', 'Cr'),
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    description = models.TextField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=1,
        choices=CATEGORIES)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('issue_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

form:

```
class IssueForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Issue
        fields = ('title','description', 'category',)
```

view

```
class IssueCreateView(CreateView):
    form_class = IssueForm

    def form_valid(self,form):
        obj = form.save(commit=False)
        obj.author = self.request.user
        obj.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

url

```
url(r'^new/', IssueCreateView.as_view(), name='issue_create'),
```

template

```
<form action="/issue/new/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ issueform.as_p }}

  </form>
```

Comment: Here: `IssueCreateView.as_view()`, try passing the `success_url` - like this: `IssueCreateView.as_view(success_url=reverse('url-name-here')))`

Comment: @karthikr I tried, doesn't solve it.

Comment: Ok. I assume you changed `url-name-here` with the success URL name

Comment: @karthikr yes I did. Btw I have edited the question to add another error on form invalid

Comment: You need to define the template to be used via the ``template_name``  class-level constant, just like the error tells you to. Like in the examples in [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#form-handling-with-class-based-views)

Comment: @sk1p I do not want to use a template. The form must appear in the template of another view, where I pass the form class to the context and use `<form action={% url 'create_issue'%}>` to enable the form.

Comment: You can override ``form_invalid`` to redirect to the other view, but that won't display the form errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`ModelFormMixin.form_valid`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/e4708385fde278fbbff5428f756632455c2bcaf5/django/views/generic/edit.py#L147), which you are overriding, sets `self.object` to the newly created object, which is then used by [`get_success_url`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/e4708385fde278fbbff5428f756632455c2bcaf5/django/views/generic/edit.py#L128). Try `self.object = obj` in `form_valid` and `get_success_url` should work again.

Comment: Thanks, this solves it. Btw, I added another error that Django throws when I submit a form that is not valid (missing required fields). I have edited that to the question.

Answer (score 3):

sk1p is correct about your first issue, though I would use `super()` and write it in a bit more concise way:

```
class IssueCreateView(CreateView):
    form_class = IssueForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super(IssueCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Using `super` will usually eliminate all issues from overriding a method, allowing you to customise behaviour without the need to reimplement the logic of the overridden method.

About your second issue:

Usually, a form is posted to it's own url, or at least a basic page is supplied if there are errors. You can add a basic template that shows the form with all it's errors if there are any on the first submission.

If you want to redirect back to the original form page, you'll lose the `POST` data on the redirect. There is however an easy workaround to this: you can save the `POST` data in the users session, and if this data is available on the page containing the form, use that to bind the form:

```
class IssueCreateView(CreateView):
    form_class = IssueForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super(IssueCreateView, self).form_valid(form)

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        self.request.session['ISSUE_CREATE_FORM_DATA'] = self.request.body
        return HttpResponseRedicect(reverse('form-url'))
```

And in your form view:

```
from django.http import QueryDict

def form_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    form_data = QueryDict(request.session.pop('ISSUE_CREATE_FORM_DATA', ''))
    form = IssueForm(form_data)
    ...
```

This requires the session middleware to be installed (`'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware'`).